# Backing tempfs with disk instead of RAM/SWAP

Tags: linux, mount, tmpfs

I want to limit the size of folder, so that a process cannot write more then `x MB` data to that folder. Looks like its not possible to do this in linux for folders but it can be done on `tempfs filesystem`.

So i can create a tempfs filesystem and set a size limit on it.

But the problem is `tempfs` is backed by RAM (and swap) which is not acceptable for my case as i will run out of disk space. Can i back the tempfs with a existing folder on disk?

I want to create around 50 such directories and set a cap of 500MB on each of those.

EDIT 1:
What does following command do?

`sudo mount -t tmpfs  /tmp /tmp/mnt/aks2`

I guess it mounts folder `/tmp` as mountpoint `/tmp/mnt/aks2` . Does that mean `/tmp/mnt/aks2` mount point is backed by /tmp folder instead of RAM? If yes why do i -t tmpfs in the command?

Answer (score 2):

No. Just create a filesystem in a file of the maximum size desired and loopmount that instead.

e.g.:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=image.img bs=1MiB count=500
mke2fs image.img
sudo mount image.img /mnt
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But can u provide some details about how it works?ALso i posted a new edit can u comment on that

Comment: It creates a filesystem in a file and loopmounts it.